# Find a file and execute a command in the file's directory

Tags: find

I am trying to use find so it would find a script file and if found execute it in the same directory it found it in.

Something like this:

```
find . -name "CLEAN" -execdir "CLEAN" {} \;
```

except `{}` is the found file itself, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest:

```
find . -type f -name "CLEAN" -execdir ./CLEAN \;
```

and in CLEAN, set your pwd rather than having it passed:

```
#!/bin/sh

MYDIR=`pwd`
echo "${MYDIR}"
```

Comment: I get this: find: The current directory is included in the PATH environment variable, which is insecure in combination with the -execdir action of find.  Please remove the current directory from your $PATH (that is, remove "." or leading or trailing colons)

Comment: Changed the $PATH to not include . and it worked..thanks!

Comment: Good to hear!  Keep in mind that there are some security concerns, especially if the above gets run by root in any user-controlled directories, as they could create their own scripts and have them run as root, but I'll assume that you are on top of that.

Answer (score 1):

if "CLEAN" is shell script file

than this work

```
  find . -name "CLEAN.sh" -execdir sh -c './CLEAN.sh' sh {} \;
```

this command file CLEAN.sh and it execute in finding directory.