# How to use `find -exec` to execute command in directory of found file (not current directory)?

Tags: find

Let's say I'm in a directory which has some subdirectories, `dir1`, `dir2`, and `dir3`.  Each of these directories have a file `foo` and I would like to execute the same command on each `foo` in each of the directories and have that command executed from inside that directory.

If I were to do it "by hand", it would look something like this:

```
cd dir1
(execute on foo)
cd ../dir2
(execute on foo)
cd ../dir3
(execute on foo)
```

It is imperative that the command be executed *from each of the directories*.  `foo` is a batch scheduling script (for HTCondor, if you care to know) and must be executed from each subdirectory so that the output of the runs started by the scheduling scripts will end up in each subdirectory.

The question "[Find a file and execute a command in the file's directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191110/find-a-file-and-execute-a-command-in-the-files-directory)", as far as I can tell, does not answer my question. The first answer to that question is more of a workaround which will not work in my case, and the second answer does not have enough of an explanation for me to know how to use it.

Answer (score 48):

Assuming your `find` supports it, use the `-execdir` option instead of `-exec`

```
find . -type f -name 'foo' -execdir pwd \;
```

This will change into each directory in turn, and if there's a `foo` file present there it will run `pwd`.

NB You cannot repurpose this solution for running commands inside directories named `foo`. For that you'd need to revert to a simple `-exec sh -c '...'` approach, iterating across the args supplied to `sh` and using `cd` for each in turn:

```
find . -type d -name 'foodir' -exec sh -c '
    for d in "$@"; do ( cd "$d" || exit; pwd ); done
    ' _ {} +
```

Comment: When you start hitting "find: The relative path ‘./node_modules/.bin’ is included in the PATH environment variable,": https://askubuntu.com/questions/621132/why-using-the-execdir-action-is-insecure-for-directory-which-is-in-the-path/1109378#1109378

Comment: on WSL doesn't work to do a git pull inside any matching directory, like  `find . -maxdepth 1  -type d -name "repo-*" -execdir git pull {} +`

Comment: @tuxErrante you want to run `git pull` inside the matching directory, but `execdir` runs insidenthe directory *containing* the matching directory (i.e., the parent directory). I suspect that's also uav's problem.

Comment: @muru you're right, I've already solved here :) https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/697912/130710

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you know exactly what directories to run your command in,

```
for dir in dir1 dir2 dir3; do
    ( cd "$dir" && somecommand foo )
done
```

or, looping over the `foo` files,

```
for foo in ./*/foo; do
  ( cd "${foo%/foo}" && somecommand foo )
done
```

The subshell prevents the `cd` to affect the working directory of the rest of the script.  The `${foo%/foo}` parameter substitution expands to the name of the directory where the `foo` file lives (by removing the knows suffix string `/foo` from the value of `$foo`).

Using standard `find` to do the same thing (in the case where the `foo` files may live deep down in a directory structure):

```
find . -type f -name foo -exec sh -c '
    for foo do
        ( cd "${foo%/foo}" && somecommand foo )
    done' sh {} +
```

In words: *Find all regular files called "foo" anywhere in the current directory or below and give their pathnames to this shell script in batches. The shell script shall iterate over the given pathnames, change directory to the directory portion of each pathname and if that succeeds, execute `somecommand foo`.*

For a solution that uses the nonstandard `-execdir`, see [roaima's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/295967/116858).  His answer adapted to my example:

```
find . -type f -name foo -execdir somecommand foo ';'
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not beautiful, but I think it does the job

```
find . -name 'foo' -type f -exec sh -c 'cd $(echo {}|cut -d"/" -f2) && ./foo' \;
```

Answer (score -1):

Tested in WSL and GitBash over Win 10.

execdir from previous solutions won't work because the command will execute using the current directory as an argument, not into it.
You can just cd into the directory and do what you want.
E.g. this is what I use to update all my repos before starting to work

```
find $HOME/workspace/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "repo*" -exec bash -c "cd \"{}\" && echo ____Pulling from \"{}\" && git pull" \;
```

EDIT:
If you're not on your personal PC/laptop and need more robust code, you should write a script not injectable with external commands, like:

```
#!/bin/sh
find "$HOME/workspace/" -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c '
  for dir in "$@"
  do
    echo "____Pulling from $dir"
    cd "$dir"
    git pull
  done' sh {} +
```

Comment: **Never embed `{}` in the code argument of some language interpreter such as bash**. That makes it a command injection vulnerability. That's also non-standard and non-portable. See [How do I properly escape weird characters in a bash script?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/389059) or [use find -exec with a filename containing a dollar sign ($)](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/569102) or [How to escape shell metacharacters automatically with \`find\` command?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/262072) and many others here.

Comment: there is no referring here to production code or server side scripting. I've also added the environment where it works. In the end is the only solution that actually does what OP asked for and it was downvoted :)

Comment: It is enough that a filename contains double quotes followed by a semi-colon, and the rest of the filename can be a shell command that should be executed. Try the first command with a directory called `repo"; echo oops;`.

Comment: "_In the end is the only solution that actually does what OP asked for_" - actually, no. Your solution expects a target directory and `cd`'s into that. The OP expects a target file and needs to `cd` into its parent directory

Comment: @tuxErrante I've updated my answer to show an example of what I've described