# loop to traverse subdirectories and execute a perl script into each subdirectory

Tags: shell

I have a parent directory with multiples subdirectories like this

```
Parent_directory
    subdirectory_1
        perlscript.pl 
        file.fasta
    subdirectory_2
        perlscript.pl 
        file_2.fasta
```

And I would like to run the perl scipt in each subdirectory. I'm trying with the next command

```
find . -type d | while read d; do perl hoz-3-v1c.pl $d/* ; done
```

but the output is directed to the parent directory and I want the output in each subdirectory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use \`find -exec\` to execute command in directory of found file (not current directory)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295965/how-to-use-find-exec-to-execute-command-in-directory-of-found-file-not-curre)

Comment: `find /path/to/Parent_directory -type f -name '*.pl' -execdir perl ./"{}" . \;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't have to bother with `find` at all in this instance.

```
for dirpath in Parent_directory/*/; do
    ( cd "$dirpath" && perl perlscript.pl *.fasta )
done
```

This assumes that the Perl script is always called `perlscript.pl` (as in your example directory layout) and that correct way to run your Perl script inside each directory is

```
perl perlscript.pl *.fasta
```

In the loop above, the parentheses creates a subshell.  This prevents the `cd` from affecting the rest of the script and we don't have to `cd` back out of the directory after running the Perl script.

The loop will iterate over all subdirectories of `Parent_directory` and execute the given commands in each.

Answer (score 0):

If your `find` supports the `-execdir` predicate (GNU, BSDs at least):

```
find . -name perlscript.pl -execdir sh -c 'exec perl ./perlscript.pl *.fasta' \;
```

searches for the `perlscript.pl` files and runs `perl` on it with the current directory set to the directory where it's found.

We need a shell to expand the `*.fasta` glob.